# spring security intercept url roles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In the spring security intercept-url config, if I define a particular role for a particular path, say ROLE_USER, that path should be accessible only if the user has that authority. That makes sense, but if I set the role as ROLE_ANONYMOUS, `<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>` shouldn't it be accessible even when the user is authenticated, say when the user has an authority ROLE_USER? But that doesn't happen.

Here is the log

```
Checking match of request : '/resources/js/test.js'; against '/resources/**'
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/js/test.js; Attributes: [ROLE_ANONYMOUS]
Previously Authenticated:   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken***********************************************
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@1712310, returned: -1
```

And then i get an access denied exception.I know it works fine if i add `<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>` in my Http config. But in the above case, is it meant to be like that or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the right way to write:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
```

You can check the [official reference manual chapter about annonymous authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/anonymous.html#anonymous-config) where you'll see following configuration:

```
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
  <property name="securityMetadata">
    <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
      <security:intercept-url pattern='/index.jsp' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern='/hello.htm' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern='/logoff.jsp' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern='/login.jsp' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER'/>
    </security:filter-security-metadata-source>" +
  </property>
</bean>
```

Your understanding of ROLE_ANONYMOUS and ROLE_USER is a bit wrong, read more about them in [this answer by Luke Taylor, one of Spring Security's devs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436554/708434).

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly : no, a resource protected with only access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" should not be accessible for authenticated users in your case. You have to explicitly tell spring to allow users with "ROLE_USER" to access it.
Depending on the version you are using, maybe you should consider using [expression-based access control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html). This way you could make a resource accessible to everyone by just using : access="permitAll()" which IMHO is simpler.