# Spring - How to protect RESTful private resources?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've some RESTful services, implemented with Spring MVC, exposing a set of resources. I already use authentication, based on HTTPBasicAuthentication and HTTPS. Some of the resources must be accessible only to some users.

For example, I want that all sub-resources in the URI `/users/{userid}/photos` are accessible only to the user `userid`. Actually in my application they are accessible to all authenticated users. How can I protect them from other users except `userid`?
And what if I want to allow access to this resources only to a subset of users (like, for example, `userid`'s friends)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `@PreAuthorize("authentication.name == #userId")`, instead of `@Secured(value = {"userid"})` or `@Secured(value = {"#userid"})` like suggested, that were not working.

Note it's necessary to add `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` to the servlet context configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

you could do something like this on your method:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userid}/photos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Secured(value = {"userid"})
    public ResponseEntity<ModelMap> getPhotos(....) throws Exception {
```

you can add more users if you want in the future by just doing

```
    @Secured(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN", "userid"})
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing these Spring Security functionalities.

Comment: No worry, glad is useful for you :)

Comment: To be thorough, it's necessary to enable security annotation adding `<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />` in the spring security context file.

Comment: are you sure it's possible to specify a value like `"userid"` in `@Secured` annotation? I can't get it working, and in all examples I've found it's used to specify a role, like `@Secured({ROLE_ADMIN})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom security expression.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/users/{userid}/photos" access="getUserIdUrlPathParameter() == principal.userId"/>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185070/spring-securityintercept-url-pattern-access-id-1/14199105#14199105) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to use Spring Security. Using Spring security you can restrict access to a specific URL endpoints to principals owning specific roles.

See [spring security intercept url roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035099/spring-security-intercept-url-roles)

You can also use JSR-250 annotations: see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126395-How-to-secure-Spring-MVC-controllers-using-Spring-Security-annotations

--

I do not think you need to restrict the URL /resource/{user} to that specific user. You should deduct the user name from the security context and not let someone inject a specific use name by forging the URL...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but @Razh's one was more specific. Moreover, from a RESTful point of view, it's more correct to have `/resource/{user}` to represent user's resources, rather than deduct the user identity from security context, also in the perspective that some roles (es. admin) can access even this resources.