# Spring Security, Customizing Authorization, AccessDecisionManager vs Security Filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm going to implement a custom authorization based on ([User<-->Role<-->Right]) model and Rights should be compared to controller and method name (e.g. "controller|method").

I used customizing UserDetails and AuthenticationProvider to adjust granted authority ([here](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/blog/spring-security-with-roles-and-rights)), but as checked source codes and docs about how customizing the compare of authority I found there is a filter [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.java)) that implements isGranted and isUserInRole to compare authority, while the documents say using AccessDecisionManager voters to customize (As I understood). Which one should be used ? Where I have controller and method(action) name to compare authority with them ?

I got confused about Spring security a little. Is there any other resource than official docs that illustrate how it works, I mean sequence of actions and methods and how customize them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several approaches:

1. Role based, where you assign each user a role and check the role before proceeding
2. Using Spring security expressions
3. There is also a new spring acl components which lets you perform acl control on class level and are stored in a database.
   My personal usage so far has been 1 and 2, where you only assign roles to users.
   But option 3 allows you to create finer grained security model, without having to rebuild your webapp when chaning the security model

**Role Based**

A role based security mechanism can be realised implementing the UserDetailsService interface and configuring spring security to use this class.

To learn on how to such a project can be realized, take a look at the following tutorials:

- Form based login with in memory user database [Link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/login-form-based-spring-3-security-example/)
- Form based login with custom userdetails service [Link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/)

In short spring security performs the following behind the scenes:

1. Upon authentication (e.g. submitting a login form) an Authentication Object is created which holds the login credentials. For example the [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) creates an [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html)
2. The authentication object is passed to an [AuthenticationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html), which can be thought of as the controller in the authentication process. The default implementation is the [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html)
3. The AuthenticationManager performs authentication via an [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). The default implementation used is the [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html).
4. The DaoAuthenticationProvider performs authentication by retrieving the [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) from a [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html). The UserDetails can be thought of as a data Object which contains the user credentials, but also the Authorities/Roles of the user! The DaoAuthenticationProvider retrieves the credentials via its [loadUserByUsername](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29) method
   and then compare it to the supplied UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
5. UserDetailsService collects the user credentials, the authorities and builds an UserDetails object out of it. For example you can retrieve a password hash and authorities out of a database. When configuring the website url-patterns you can refer to the authorities in the access [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035099/spring-security-intercept-url-roles).  Furthermore, you can retrieve the Authentication object in your controller classes via the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().

Furthemore to get a better understanding of the inner workings of these classes you can read the javadocs:

- [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) - how the user credentials are stored and accessed
- [AuthenticationManager.authenticate(..)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html#authenticate%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29) - contract on how AuthenticationExceptions are handled
- [UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(..)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29)- contact on how username lookup failures are handled, e.g. user does not exist

**Spel**

Instead of checking authorities, [SPEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) enables you also to check other properties of a user.
You can use these in the URL patterns, but also annotate methods with @Preauthorize. 
This way securing the business layer is less intrusive.

**ACL Based**

The ACL based model was introduced in spring security 3.0, but hasn't been well [documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/domain-acls.html).
Their suggestion is to look at the [Contacts XML example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/domain-acls.html), since this one uses their new acl component.

Last [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849518262) contains great examples on how to further customize your security wishes.